# How do I print a Ruby regex variable?

Tags: ruby, regex

How do I print/display just the part of a regular expression that is between the slashes?

```
irb> re = /\Ahello\z/
irb> puts "re is /#{re}/"
```

The result is:

```
re is /(?-mix:\Ahello\z)/
```

Whereas I want:

```
re is /\Ahello\z/
```

...but not by doing this craziness:

```
puts "re is /#{re.to_s.gsub( /.*:(.*)\)/, '\1' )}/"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see the original pattern between the delimiters, use `source`:

```
IP_PATTERN = /(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}/
IP_PATTERN # => /(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}/
IP_PATTERN.inspect # => "/(?:\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}/"
IP_PATTERN.to_s # => "(?-mix:(?:\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3})"
```

Here's what `source` shows:

```
IP_PATTERN.source # => "(?:\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}"
```

From [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html#method-i-source):

```
Returns the original string of the pattern.

    /ab+c/ix.source #=> "ab+c"

Note that escape sequences are retained as is.

    /\x20\+/.source  #=> "\\x20\\+"
```

NOTE:

It's common to build a complex pattern from small patterns, and it's tempting to use interpolation to insert the simple ones, but that doesn't work as most people think it will. Consider this:

```
foo = /foo/
bar = /bar/imx
foo_bar = /#{ foo }_#{ bar }/
foo_bar # => /(?-mix:foo)_(?mix:bar)/
```

Notice that `foo_bar` has the pattern flags for each of the sub-patterns. Those can *REALLY* mess you up when trying to match things if you're not aware of their existence. Inside the `(?-...)` block the pattern can have totally different settings for `i`, `m` or `x` in relation to the outer pattern. Debugging that can make you nuts, worse than trying to debug a complex pattern normally would. How do I know this? I'm a veteran of that particular war.

This is why `source` is important. It injects the exact pattern, without the flags:

```
foo_bar = /#{ foo.source}_#{ bar.source}/
foo_bar # => /foo_bar/
```

Comment: So, `puts "re is \/#{re.source}\/" #=> "re is /\Ahello\z/"`.  Might [Regexp#inspect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html#method-i-inspect) be defined: `def inspect; "\/#{source}\/"; end`?

Comment: It could be that way in the Regexp class. But it'd be easier to write it `"/#{source}/"`. There's no need to escape the forward-slashes in a string.

Comment: `puts "re is /#{re.source}/"`

Answer (score 3):

Use `.inspect` instead of `.to_s`:

```
> puts "re is #{re.inspect}"
re is /\Ahello\z/
```

Comment: Or, equivalently: `print "re is "; p re #=> "re is /\Ahello\z/"`.

Comment: Yes, printing with `p` calls `inspect`, so it's more convenient if that is the only desired output (and the standard output is used). But if other text (such as the leading `re is`) is desired on the same line, I think it's cleaner to put the whole line in one call.